# openapi-generator-maven-plugin creates JsonNullable<Object> for properties with ref: #

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I've created my .yml (reduced):

```
openapi: 3.0.1
...
components:
  messages:
  ...
  schemas:
    device:
      type: object
      properties:
        identifier:
          type: string
        manufacturer:
          type: string
        model:
          type: string
    controllerId:
      type: number
    controller:
      type: object
      properties:
        controllerId:
          ref: '#/components/schemas/controllerId'
        device:
          ref: '#/components/schemas/device'
```

I let generate java classes for Vertx by

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.3.0</version>
```

Properties with `type:` are generated as expected but all properties with `ref:` are generated as `JsonNullable<Object>`.
Because of that the jackson-`ObjectMapper` reads the values as `LinkedHashMap` instead of e. g. `Device` in `Controller`'s field.

I copied the generated classes and fixed the generics so the mapper reads the values to the expected classes.
Do you have any idea how to write the .yml that the generator creates `JsonNullable<Device>` instead of `JsonNullable<Object>`?
Or is there any configuration of the generator I didn't found yet to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the specs...
I had to change `ref:` to `$ref` and the correct member type is generated.

Comment: I'm using $ref: but still seeing JsonNullables in the created code. Was there anything else you changed? ( I know this was 2 years ago, just hoping maybe you remember)